# A possible object cycle was detected. in both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, .net-5

I have been pulling my hair out with this one.

I have a very simple test class that throws this error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

It doesn't seem to break much, as the put request is successful and the serialize is also successful.

**EDIT**

I have chased the serialize exception out if it was ever really there.  I am starting to think it is a problem with typed HttpClient.  It throws the exception that comes out on the console and in the response on Postman.  However, it doesn't allow me to catch the exception in the code and the PUT call works.  So the exception is happening after the PUT request and is handled before it returns control to my app.

I am going to try to use a standard HttpClientFactor instead of a typed client and see if that works.  I know that the JSON exception is a red herring, but it is ugly and breaking the response.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
public virtual async Task<CouchResponse> Create(string id, string db, TObj info)
{
  CouchResponse ret = new() { Reason = "Unknown and unExpected error", Ok = false };
  HttpResponseMessage rc = null;

  if (id is null)
  {
    return new CouchResponse() { Id = "missing", Ok = false, Rev = "missing" };
  }
  string url = $"{db}/1";
  try
  {
    // login to Couchdb servwer
    await CouchLogin();

    try
    {

      //var jsonInfo = JsonUtils.Serialize<TestJson>(jTest);
      var jsonInfo = JsonSerializer.Serialize<TObj>(info, options);
      HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonInfo, Encoding.UTF8, 
        "application/json");
      rc = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
    } 
    catch (Exception eNewton)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Json Exception: {eNewton.Message}");
    }

    if (rc is not null)
    {
      var str = await rc.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      var ret = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CouchResponse>(str,options);
      rc.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return ret;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    //return ret;

  }
  return ret;
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I did.  I newed up class, then tried to serialize it and I get an error.

Comment: `var jsonInfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jTest,jsonSerializerSettings);` does not throw an exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ko6Gww.  Can you share a [mcve]?  Your `ClientBase<T>` class doesn't compile because `IDbAccess<>`, `CouchResponse` and `CouchLogin` are not defined, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/O2MMlP.  Without a compilable and runnable [mcve] we're unlikely to be able to help.  Simply sharing the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any might clarify things.

Comment: This is a crazy bug.  For some reason httpClient.SendAsync is throwing the JSON error.  However, it isn't bubbling up to the application, but stack trace is being returned in the response message.  I am going to continue to play with it but may open a question on SendAsync.

Answer (score 1):

What a crazy bug.  The diagnostic was very missing leading.  Everything I was doing in the create method was correct.

What is missed was an await when I called the create method.  This made it appear that the sendAsync was having the issue when it was really the controller trying to format the task return as a response.  This caused the stack trace in the response message.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
      NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
```

To this

```
        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
          ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
          NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
          MaxDepth = null,
        };
```